# Inferring age with lookaheads in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a bunch of tweets and various metadata that I want to analyze for sociolinguistic purposes. In order to do this, I'm trying to infer users' ages thanks to the information they provide in their bio, among others.
For that I'm using regular expressions to match a couple of recurring patterns in users' bio, like a user mentioning a number followed by various spellings of "years old" as in:

"John, 30 years old, engineer."

However, I also want to check for what comes after "years old", as many people mention their children's age, and I don't want this to be incorrectly associated to the user's age, as in:

"John, father of a 12 year old kid, engineer"

So cases as the one above should be ignored, so that I can only keep users for whom a valid age can be inferred.

My program looks like this:

```
import csv
import re

with open("test_corpus.csv") as corpus:
    corpus_read = csv.reader(corpus, delimiter=",")
    for row in corpus_read:
        if re.findall(r"\d{2}\s?(?=years old\s?|yo\s?|yr old\s?|y o\s?|yrs old\s?|year old\s?(?!son|daughter|kid|child))",row[5].lower()):
            age = re.findall(r"\d{2}\s?",row[5].lower())
            for i in age:
                print(i)
```

The program seems to work in some cases, but in the small test file I created to try it out, it incorrectly matches the age mentioned in the string "I have a 12 yo son", and returns 12 as a matched age, which I don't want it to. I'm guessing this has something to do with brackets or delimiters at some point in the program, but I spent a few hours on it, and I could not find anything helpful on the forum, so any help would be appreciated.

Thus, the actual question is: how to make the program not recognize 12 in "John, father of a 12 year old kid, engineer" as the age of the user, based on the program I already have?

I am somewhat new at programming, so apologies if I forgot to mention something important, do not hesitate to tell me if you need more details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regex would not be the way to go, in my opinion.  You need to parse this into tokens and invest in some NLTK processing.  http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: how this phrase `"John, father of a 12 year old kid, engineer"` should be treated?

Comment: Thanks for your insight, and for the link @duffymo, but the reason I want to use regex is that there are actually very few ways people mention their age on Twitter, and being able to match three or four different patterns would allow me to infer the ages of most of the users in my corpus. I intend to use nltk at a later stage, but right now I don't really see how that would be more efficient than regex, but I'll take a closer look at it, thank you! : )

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it should not be treated at all, I am trying to only keep users for whom I can infer a valid age. Thanks for asking the question, I should have mentioned that earlier, I'll edit the original post.

Comment: So, you basically want to parse the English language with regular expressions? This looks like an impossible mission. You'd better parse the sentences into tokens and do some analysis with an ANN or NLTK or something similar.

Comment: @ForceBru Not the English language as a whole, but as I mentioned in an earlier comment, there are actually three or four main ways people mention their age on Twitter, so I just need regexes which match those three or four cases, and the one I'm struggling with right now is one of these ways of mentioning one's age. But thanks for recommending NLTK, I indeed plan to use it later, when I will analyze the data. : )

Comment: Look, what if you simply check whether son/kid/daughter etc. appear within 2 words of the age? You don't need regexes for that. Also, I think that a simple naive bayes classifier can help you a lot, and should be rather quick to train

Comment: @BlackBear hmmmm, the point about checking whether son/kid etc appear within 2 words of the age is a good one, and that could be a condition I could add to the positive lookahead, which is working, so why not keep it?... Thanks a lot!
Concerning naive bayes classifiers, I honestly don't know what these are, so I don't think I could use them, but I'll take a look at it too, thanks for the help! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few days of tweaking the program around, and above all, of asking around, I have been able to solve the problem! I could not give a detailed explanation, as I am not sure to fully understand it myself, but the problem seemed to be the position of the spaces in the code. However if anyone has a technical and properly formulated explanation to give, feel free to do so.

Anyways, the solution is to do:

```
import csv 
import re

with open("test_bio.csv") as corpus:
corpus_read = csv.reader(corpus, delimiter=",")
for row in corpus_read:
    if re.search(r"\d{2}\s?(?=(?:years old|yo|yr old|y o|yrs old|year old)(?!\s?son|\s?daughter|\s?kid|\s?child))" ,row[5].lower()):
        age2 = re.findall(r"\d{2}\s?",row[5].lower())
        for z in age2:
            print(z)
```

Thanks again for your help!